# How can I refresh a list (*ngFor) onChange when using <ion-searchbar>

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic3

I am not sure how to phrase this question correctly, so I'll show the core-code and then describe my problem below.

```
<ion-searchbar 
        [(ngModel)]="autoc" 
        (ionInput)="updateSearch()" 
        (ionCancel)="dismiss()"
</ion-searchbar>
<ion-list>
    <ion-item *ngFor="let item of autocompleteItems" 
        {{ item.description }}
    </ion-item>
</ion-list>
```

Whenever the searchbar gets a new value, it calls the updateSearch function - that works.
In the updateSearch function, I'm pushing data into the autocompleteItems array, which I use to list every item in the array (like in the code above). Here is the updateSearch function:

```
 updateSearch(){
    ...
     predictions.forEach(function (prediction) {              
        self.autocompleteItems.push(prediction);
     });
    }
```

My problems is that my list of items doesn't get updated after I type something in the searchbar. I have to either type one more letter or focus on something outside the searchbar. So when I type "Stackstreet 5", it wouldn't show "Stackstreet 5" right away (it would show "Stackstreet", I would have to add in an extra space or something similar, to get the "new update". 
To summarize: the ion-item with *ngFor="let item of autocompleteItems" doesn't update onChange (ionInput), but the updateSearch runs though. So I would have to somehow refresh/update the list in the html. How can I solve that?

Answer (score 0):

Fixed by using a Promise. I doubt that this was Ionics fault - could be the Google API giving me a hard time.

Anyway, here is the code that I replaced if anyone is interested. 
[inside updateSearch()]

```
  this.getPlacesBySearch()
            .then((predictions) => self.autocompleteItems = predictions)
            .catch(error => {
                self.autocompleteItems = [];
                console.log('error', error)
    })
```

Works like a charm!